# data race between ip::tcp::socket::async_connect & io_service::run ?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, valgrind

I'm getting helgrind errors using asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_connect while at the same time io_service::run is running in a thread pool. The reports is:

---

Possible data race during read of size 8 at 0x507bb50 by thread #6

==13316==    at 0xDDF1CC: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::perform_io(unsigned int) (epoll_reactor.ipp:610)

==13316==    by 0xDDF355: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) (epoll_reactor.ipp:648)

==13316==    by 0xD7CF93: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) (task_io_service_operation.hpp:37)

==13316==    by 0xE17469: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::thread_info&, boost::asio::detail::op_queue&, boost::system::error_code const&) (task_io_service.ipp:394)

==13316==    by 0xE1713B: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) (task_io_service.ipp:146)

==13316==    by 0xE176FC: boost::asio::**io_service::run()** (io_service.ipp:59)

==13316==    by 0xF97421: Common::ServiceRunner::ServiceThread() (ServiceRunner.cpp:67)
....

**This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #9**

==13316==    at 0xDDE5EF: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::register_descriptor(int, boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state*&) (epoll_reactor.ipp:156)

==13316==    by 0xE75C34: boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::do_open(boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type&, int, int, int, boost::system::error_code&) (reactive_socket_service_base.ipp:152)

==13316==    by 0xE7B6E2: boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service::open(boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service::implementation_type&, boost::asio::ip::tcp const&, boost::system::error_code&) (reactive_socket_service.hpp:106)

==13316==    by 0xE79FF7: boost::asio::stream_socket_service::**open**(boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service::implementation_type&, boost::asio::ip::tcp const&, boost::system::error_code&) (stream_socket_service.hpp:127)

==13316==    by 0xE78904: void boost::asio::basic_socket >::**async_connect** >, boost::_bi::list3 >, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::_bi::value > > > > >(boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint const&, boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler >, boost::_bi::list3 >, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::_bi::value > > > > const&) (basic_socket.hpp:712)
==13316== by 0xE7376B: Common::Comms::TCPClient::HandleResolve(boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator) (TCPClient.cpp:297)

---

***I found that async_connect is not real problem, but opening a socket is, when io_service::run is running.***

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: post your code exhibiting the race condition

Comment: @SamMiller  The code is quite lengthy, but in short, it's quite simple:
(1). there are many threads running io_service::run()
(2). ip::tcp::socket::async_connect() is called with non-open socket

Comment: you don't need to include all of the code, just the relevant part showing the race condition. This is part of debugging. Turning this into a [sscce](http://sscce.org) will enable us to help you.

Comment: cool, I'll try shortly

Comment: Looks like you access the socket from multiple thread: 1) in thread#9 you call async_connect 2) in thread#6 you access the socket from a completion handler -- don't you?